# Regex Replace in VB.Net

Tags: regex, vb.net, replace

i have a little problem in VB.Net, i have a string containing Time in this format:

```
Dim _Date as String = "15-12-35"
```

That Means 15.12 pm and 35sec.
I just wanna replace the "-" with ":" but i can't understand how to use regex to do it, Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple string find/replace, but if you want regex you can use:

```
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace("15-12-35", "-", ":")
```

If you want to use maybe a non literal, you could use `\D` (non digits)

```
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace("15-12-35", "\D", ":")
```

Update: if you want to match whatever numbers and replace with capturing groups, then you could:

```
Dim output As String = Regex.Replace("15-12-35", "(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)", "$1:$2:$3")
```